# One column is Date and another column is Status but i need only after changed to status dates how to find?

Tags: sql-server

Current input:

```
Date         Status
--------------------
6/20/2016    ABC
6/21/2016    ABC
6/22/2016    ABC
6/23/2016    DEF 
6/24/2016    ABC 
6/25/2016    ABC
6/26/2016    ABC
6/27/2016    ABC
```

Desired output:

```
Date        Status 
-------------------
6/24/2016   ABC
6/25/2016   ABC
6/26/2016   ABC
6/27/2016   ABC
```

Above is my input and expected out put. what ever dates after changed status ABC continuously then showcase remaining changed before ABC is no need.

Comment: I *tried* to guess what you really meant - this was really a horribly bad question. Not sure if I got it correctly - please, next time: **put some more effort** into creating your question!! If you're expecting **us** to spend our own, spare time on helping you, then **YOU** could **AT LEAST** present an understandable, comprehensive question....

Comment: ok marc_s this was my first job i just learning if anything wrong forgive but what ever you arranged 100% correct i am expecting please help the code in sql server

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (dt date,status varchar(3))
insert into @t values
('2016-06-20',   'ABC'),
('2016-06-21',   'ABC'),
('2016-06-22' ,  'ABC'),
('2016-06-23' ,  'DEF'),
('2016-06-24' ,  'ABC'),
('2016-06-25' ,  'ABC'),
('2016-06-26',   'ABC'),
('2016-06-27' ,  'ABC')

select * from @t
where   dt > (select max(dt) from @t where status <> 'ABC')
```